# Stargazer puts an additional $...$ around the minus sign of a negative numeric value

Tags: stargazer

If I have a negative numeric value in R that I want to output into latex code using stargazer, I get something like:

```
$$-$ 2$
```

which Latex cannot handle because there is no space between the first two Dollar signs. This occurs if stargazer interprets a negative value:

```
library("stargazer")
stargazer(-2, summary=F) # delete the minus sign to see the difference, it'll be: $2$
```

How can I avoid that? Latex is completely fine with getting $- 2$ and interprets that as math so how can I either get rid of those extra dollar signs around the  minus sign or, as a workaround, add a space between the two dollar signs? My real table is of course huge which makes manual updating infeasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting align = TRUE should fix your problem. Stargazer uses then the dcolumn package and generates the following output:

```
> stargazer(c(-0.2, 1, -2), summary = FALSE, float = FALSE, header = FALSE, align = TRUE)

\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
-0.200 & 1 & -2 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}
```

If, for whatever reason, you cannot or do not want to use the dcolumn package you can also manually substitute the unwanted signs by:

```
t <- stargazer(c(-0.2, 1, -2), summary = FALSE, float = FALSE, header = FALSE, align = FALSE)
t <- gsub("\\$\\$\\-\\$", "\\$\\-", t) # substitute unwanted behaviour
write.table(t, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE) # recreate latex table

\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
$-0.200$ & $1$ & $-2$ \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: As an aside, it is a bad idea to use "T" and "F" as a shortcut for "TRUE" or "FALSE". You can redefine T to be something different (e.g., number of periods in your sample), introducing bugs, which become very hard to track down. At some point, I spent literally half a day tracking down a single error because of this issue.